# concatenate two value from the yaml file in the global configuration in mule 4

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

I have to set the property placeholder dynamically from the runtime. I'm configuring ${mule.env} in the runtime but when i'm trying to append this in into the placeholder i'm getting error that value not found and error in the ${mule.env}_${secure::sfdc.token.host}.
How can I append the ${mule.env} into the ${secure::sfdc.token.host} so that it will take correct configuration value.
Below i have added my request-config and YAML.

```
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration-token" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="411c1d32-df92-44da-87d9-cca02e851db7" basePath="${mule.env}_${secure::sfdc.token.base_path}">
    <http:request-connection host="${mule.env}_${secure::sfdc.token.host}" />
    </http:request-config>
```

yaml:

```
       uat_sfdc:
         token:
            base_path: "/services/uat"
            host: "0.0.0.0"
       prod_sfdc:
         token:
            base_path: "/services/prod"
            host: "0.0.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to have your yaml files in the directory which belongs to one environment. 
Like /var/mule/DEV/app1/global.yaml, /var/mule/TEST/app1/global.yaml, /var/mule/PROD/app1/global.yaml and use mule.env variable to select the environmen. So path to config file will be /var/mule/${mule.env}/app1/global.yaml

In this case you don't need logic inside app to find properies and, more imprtant, your DEV does not know about PROD and cannot accidentally corrupt PDOD data.

Read about proeprties here https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/Properties.html

Comment: that solution I was doing but the requirement has been changed and I have to configure everything in one yaml. So please let me know how can we do this.

Comment: You can do p('${mule.env}.toke.host'}) or something[${mule.env}].somethingelse.host or something similar. Or simply set variable env with p('${mule.env}') and then use it as usual env.token.host